# Android setOnClickListener is not working on first click after launching the app

Tags: android, fragment

In setOnClickListener i am passing url to method in another class from fragment for downloading images, But after launching the app it is not working on first click(it is displaying Toast message but image is not downloading) But from second click it is working perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
downloadimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String[] urls = new String[50];
            for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                urls[i] = images.get(i).getLarge();

            }
            DownloadImages downloadImages= new DownloadImages();
            downloadImages.downloadImage(getActivity(),urls, images.get(0).getName());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            Log.i("TAG", "scanning File jbdv");


        }
    });
```

Here is complete DownloadImages class

```
public class DownloadImages extends AppCompatActivity {

public  void downloadImage(final Context ctx, String[]imgloc, final String folder) {

    for (int i = 0; i < imgloc.length; i++) {

        Picasso.with(ctx)
                .load(imgloc[i])
                .into(new Target() {
                          @Override
                          public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                              try {
                                  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                  File myDir = new File(root + "/~" +folder);

                                  if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                      myDir.mkdirs();
                                  }

                                  String name = new Date().getTime() + ".jpg";
                                  myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                                  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                                  out.flush();
                                  out.close();
                                  Log.i("TAG", "scanning File " +myDir.getAbsolutePath());
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                  // some action
                              }

                          }


                          @Override
                          public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                          }
                      }
                );


    }

}
```

}

Comment: put all your code here

Comment: Post this function's body- downloadImage(....){}

Comment: Are you using AsyncTask? If so, it might be still downloading - display some progress dialog and you will see if it‘s loading. Because from your code I can see that it downloads 50 Images? That is quite a lot and it might not be finished that quick.

Comment: In debug mode , images array has size > 0?

Comment: I am not using Asynk task

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in onStart() method

and for fast access of the image do it in background